# How can i animate container from square shape to parallelogram shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, customization, flutter-animation

Right Now i have a container of this kind of shape ,

[image]

I want to animate container from this shape to this one when on tap button was hit

[image]

So Who can i achieve this thing in Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve skew by using matrix transformation

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.skewX(-0.3),
  child: YourCard(),
)
```

Now all you need to do is animate -0.3 value. There are several ways to do it, depending on what you need. You could use Tween or AnimatedWidget. Since it's not easy to explain here's video that could help in choosing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXIJJkq_H8g

Answer (score 1):

You can try Transform with Matrix4

[image]

```
Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  transform: Matrix4.skewY(0.3)..rotateZ(-math.pi / 12.0),
  child: Container(
    height:300,
    width:120,
    color:Colors.orange,
    child: Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
  ),
)
```